# Maximize convex function on box constraints

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming, non-convex-optimization

I try to maximize a quadratic function on box constraints as shown below

\begin{array}{l}
\max {x^T}Qx\\
s.t.{\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} a \le {x_i} \le b
\end{array}
The length of vector $x$ is approximately $2000$ and $Q$ is symmetric. I am wondering if there exists a solver (like Cplex or Gurobi) which can solve this maximization problem efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

The problem that you've stated is in general NP-Hard, so you can't expect an "efficient" (meaning polynomial time) solver for all cases.

You haven't said anything about the convexity/concavity of the objective function.  If $Q$ is negative semi-definite, then you've got a convex QP that can easily be solved to a global optimum by many software packages for convex QP.  For example, this can easily be done with CPLEX.  If your problems are convex, $N=2000$ is big but not really huge.

If $Q$ is indefinite or even positive semidefinite, then you've got a non-convex problem that can be solved by various exponential time algorithms. 
In particular, branch and bound methods for non-convex QP work pretty well in practice.  Recent versions of CPLEX include this feature. Whether or not your particular instances will be practically solvable is impossible to say without experimenting.

Comment: If Q is negative definite, you could use quadprog in Matlab to solve it as well.

Comment: Looking back, I see that the title specified that the function was convex.  In that case you've still got the option of using branch and bound.

Comment: +1, of course, but I would say that the likelihood that someone presents us with a negative semidefinite quadratic form is pretty small ;-)